# Calculate value based on existence of records matching given criteria - FileMaker Pro 13

Tags: filemaker

How can I write a calculation field in a table that outputs '1' if there are other (related) records in the same table that meet a given set of criteria and '0' otherwise?

### Here's my problem explained in more detail:

I have a table containing 'students' and another containing 'exam results'. The 'exam results' table looks like this:

```
StudentID  SubjectID Level   Result
3234       1         2       A-
3234       2         4       B+
4739       1         4       C+
```

A student can only pass a Level 4 exam in subject 2 if they have also passed a Level 2 exam in subject 1 with a B+ or higher. I want to define a field in the 'students' table that contains a '1' if there exists an exam result belonging to the right student that meets these criteria and a '0' otherwise.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Are the pre-requisites always as simple as that: the student has passed the exam whose level is minus 1 the "current" exam? It's also not quite clear which level the calculation should consider. IMHO, you should have separate tables for Students, Exams and Results. Then you could define a Exams - Students relationship to include all students that passed each exam.

Comment: No, the prerequisites are more complicated (e.g. passing level 4 in subject A requires a level 2 pass in subject B). I tried to simplify the example for the purposes of the question. I do have separate tables for students, exams and results but I'm confused about defining this relationship—how do I leave out the students that have failed their prerequisites?

Comment: "*I tried to simplify the example for the purposes of the question.*" It's not a good idea, IMHO, because that's where the real issue seems to be. However. we need more than a single example. The two most important questions here are: **1.** Can an exam have more than one prerequisite? If yes, you will need a table for them. **2.** Are all prerequisites in the same format, e.g. {SubjectID, MinScore}?

Comment: Yes, I can see that now! I'll try to be clearer.

**1.** No, each exam has just one prerequisite

**2.** Yes, each prerequisite is of the same form {SubjectID, Level, MinResult}

Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take an example of a **Results** table where the results are also calculated as a numeric value, e.g.

```
StudentID  SubjectID Level   Result   cResultNum
3234       1         2       A-       95
3234       2         4       B+       85
4739       1         4       C+       75
```

and an **Exams** table with the following fields (among others):

- RequiredSubjectID
- RequiredLevel
- RequiredResultNum

Given these, you can construct a relationship between Exams and (another occurrence of) Results as:

```
Exams::RequiredSubjectID = Results 2::SubjectID
AND  
Exams::RequiredLevel = Results 2::Level
AND
Exams::RequiredResultNum ≤ Results 2::cResultNum
```

This allows each exam record to calculate a list of students that are eligible to take that exam as =

```
List ( Results 2::StudentID )
```

---

> I want to define a field in the 'students' table that contains a '1'
>   if there exists an exam result belonging to the right student that
>   meets these criteria and a '0' otherwise.

This request is unclear, because there are many exams a student may want to take, and a field in the Students table can calculate only one result.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I realised that the 'prerequisitesMet' field ought to belong to the 'entries' table, and using the calculation `ValueCount ( FilterValues( Exams::StudentsWithPrerequisites; StudentID ) ) or IsEmpty ( Exams::RequiredSubjectID )` I ensured that this field returns a '1' if the student had met the prerequisite (or if no prerequisite was set) and a '0' if she had not.

Comment: @drian42 You mean you test this after the fact?

Comment: This way I check that, for each entry, the student entered has passed the prerequisites for that entry. A student can sit an exam without having met the prerequisites, but they won't be awarded a pass until they have.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do a self-join in the table for the field you want to check, for example:

```
Exam::Level = Exam2::Level
Exam::Student = Exam2::Student
```

And for the "was passed" criteria I think you could do an "If" on the calculation like this:

```
If ( Last(Exam2::Result) = "D" and ...(all the  pass values) ; 1 ; 0 )
```

Edit:
It could be just with the not pass value hehe I miss that it will be like this:

```
If ( Last(Exam2::Result) = "F" ; 0 ; 1 )
```

I hope this helps you.